# Angular view doesn't update after change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a dropdown, I would like to disable it dynamically, I am using @Input to get the value from the parent component and disable it in the child component.

The @input value is returned correctly and triggered on ngOnchange, I've consoled the @input value and it returns as expected.

However, when I print the value on the HTML, the value doesn't update with onChange. (The value changes in the component, the template doesn't get updated)

I've tried this.ref.detectChanges() and ngZone still it doesn't work

HTML

```
<div ngbDropdown #commonDropdown="ngbDropdown" class="d-inline-block" style="width: 100%;" [autoClose]="true">
      <button class="btn btn-primary truncate" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle [disabled]="disableChannel">
        {{values.selected.value}}
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" style="width: 100%;">
        <button *ngFor="let value of values.data" class="dropdown-item" (click)="selectDropDown(value); commonDropdown.close();">{{value.value}}
        </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

component :

```
export class CommonComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
      @Input()
      disableChannel: boolean;
      @Input()
      values: DropDownObject;
      @Output()
      valueSelected: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();
      private selectedValues: DropDownObject;

      constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private ngZone: NgZone) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.emitSelectedValue(this.values);
      }

      ngOnChanges(simpleChanges: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(this.disableChannel);
        // boolean returns as expected however, binding in the view doesn't work. Button is not disabled when the value returns true
      }


      selectDropDown(selectedChannel): void {
        this.values.setSelected(selectedChannel);
        this.selectedValues = new DropDownObject();
        this.selectedValues.setSelected(selectedChannel);
        this.selectedValues.setData(this.values.getData());
        this.emitSelectedValue(this.selectedValues);
      }

      emitSelectedValue(data) {
        this.valueSelected.emit(data);
      }

}
```

Comment: I have distilled disabling a button down to just it's essence here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3oyevg

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thanks for the approach. My application works as expected if I set my disabled value to true on nginit. My issue is that view doesn't get updated after ngOnchange is triggered. It has nothing to do with disabling the button, my main concern is when I print the value inside the template after the ngOnchange, the value remains same. However, inside the component the value changes.

Comment: Can you create an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on stackblitz.com

Comment: What is the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` you are using ?

Comment: let me first know what is the purpose of this lines  this.values.setSelected(selectedChannel);
this.selectedValues.setSelected(selectedChannel);

Comment: is it function? you r passing selectedChannel to this for what purpose?

Comment: disableChannel should be a Boolean type, assign it globally like, this.disableChan = disableChannel; after that use it in your HTML  [disabled]="disableChan"

Comment: I have the same problem, it's strange no solution after a year!